# How to plot 3D hist in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have dataset that contains accidents in a region with a year.

```
> Accident_ID   Region   Year  
> 213              1       2003 
> 234              2       2001
> 334              2       2004
> ..


years= [0.0, 1661.0, 1665.0, 1706.0, 1729.0, 1765.0, 1779.0, 1780.0, 1785.0, 1798.0, 1799.0, 1800.0, 1801.0, 1802.0, 1804.0, 1805.0, 1812.0, 1814.0, 1816.0, 1821.0, 1822.0, 1824.0, 1825.0, 1826.0, 1827.0, 1829.0, 1830.0, 1831.0, 1832.0, 1833.0, 1834.0, 1835.0, 1836.0, 1837.0, 1838.0, 1839.0, 1840.0, 1841.0, 1842.0, 1843.0, 1844.0, 1845.0, 1846.0, 1847.0, 1848.0, 1849.0, 1850.0, 1851.0, 1852.0, 1853.0, 1854.0, 1855.0, 1856.0, 1857.0, 1858.0, 1859.0, 1860.0, 1861.0, 1862.0, 1863.0, 1864.0, 1865.0, 1866.0, 1867.0, 1868.0, 1869.0, 1870.0, 1871.0, 1872.0, 1873.0, 1874.0, 1875.0, 1876.0, 1877.0, 1878.0, 1879.0, 1880.0, 1881.0, 1882.0, 1883.0, 1884.0, 1885.0, 1886.0, 1887.0, 1888.0, 1889.0, 1890.0, 1891.0, 1892.0, 1893.0, 1894.0, 1895.0, 1896.0, 1897.0, 1898.0, 1899.0, 1900.0, 1901.0, 1902.0, 1903.0, 1904.0, 1905.0, 1906.0, 1907.0, 1908.0, 1909.0, 1910.0, 1911.0, 1912.0, 1913.0, 1914.0, 1915.0, 1916.0, 1917.0, 1918.0, 1919.0, 1920.0, 1921.0, 1922.0, 1923.0, 1924.0, 1925.0, 1926.0, 1927.0, 1928.0, 1929.0, 1930.0, 1931.0, 1932.0, 1933.0, 1934.0, 1935.0, 1936.0, 1937.0, 1938.0, 1939.0, 1940.0, 1941.0, 1942.0, 1943.0, 1944.0, 1945.0, 1946.0, 1947.0, 1948.0, 1949.0, 1950.0, 1951.0, 1952.0, 1953.0, 1954.0, 1955.0, 1956.0, 1957.0, 1958.0, 1959.0, 1960.0, 1961.0, 1962.0, 1963.0, 1964.0, 1965.0, 1966.0, 1967.0, 1968.0, 1969.0, 1970.0, 1971.0, 1972.0, 1973.0, 1974.0, 1975.0, 1976.0, 1977.0, 1978.0, 1979.0, 1980.0, 1981.0, 1982.0, 1983.0, 1984.0, 1985.0, 1986.0, 1987.0, 1988.0, 1989.0, 1990.0, 1991.0, 1992.0, 1993.0, 1994.0, 1995.0, 1996.0, 1997.0, 1998.0, 1999.0, 2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0, 2004.0, 2005.0, 2006.0, 2007.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2013.0]

Frequency_accidents_years= [44815, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 556, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 20, 11, 6, 5, 1, 7, 6, 6, 2, 4, 6, 19, 9, 11, 10, 18, 18, 8, 9, 13, 20, 43, 7, 13, 11, 6, 13, 12, 6, 7, 9, 34, 3, 2, 3, 1, 7, 6, 4, 8, 11, 56, 18, 5, 4, 4, 16, 2, 1, 3, 3, 146, 49, 10, 7, 10, 22, 18, 14, 18, 17, 397, 46, 12, 14, 12, 53, 39, 18, 28, 25095, 9663, 26717, 131, 180, 268, 7660, 754, 641, 354, 873, 47024, 705, 720, 578, 598, 16547, 653, 516, 255, 296, 92079, 1161, 1175, 1634, 2111, 71121, 3158, 3289, 4355, 2136, 77654, 33007, 1253, 983, 365, 25554, 651, 665, 762, 968, 38485, 745, 326, 199, 176, 25048, 343, 368, 604, 753, 46674, 775, 683, 562, 645, 26992, 768, 959, 816, 922, 37271, 796, 915, 1101, 945, 19687, 618, 614, 620, 509, 17169, 497, 623, 853, 854, 9755, 662, 725, 999, 593, 5469, 554, 778, 1163, 1342, 3470, 3755, 3810, 3597, 3613, 3504, 2263, 3173, 2465, 2135, 2558, 3476, 3164, 2755, 3715, 4187, 4540, 4203, 4445, 6541, 5994, 4873, 4085, 2899, 1806, 1157, 1331, 1246, 424]

regions = xrange(1,100) // Can be generated this way eg: region1, region2 ..
```

I wanna plot these data in a 3D histogram to better analyse the dataset.
I wanna plot frequency of accident via region/Year

```
from collections import Counter
data.pandas("file.csv")

.. 
.. 

#Make 3D Hist
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(xs=years, ys=Frequency_accidents_years, zs=regions, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='r',label="name")
plt.show()
```

I ended up having this problem.

I got this error:

```
line 49 ..

  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1962, in print_png
    return agg.print_png(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 505, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 270, in draw
    Axes.draw(self, renderer)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 117, in draw
    xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 194, in proj_transform
    return proj_transform_vec(vec, M)
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 153, in proj_transform_vec
    vecw = np.dot(M, vec)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (210) (858312)
```

Comment: There is a lot of code missing. Where does vec and M come from? how do you get first, sec, and r?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have put everything, I wanna plot (years, Frequency_accidents_years, regions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to come up with an example of how to plot a Matplotlib *bar3d* 3d histogram given your dataset structure using Panda's `groupby` as pointed out by **Davidmh**.

I used the following dataset based in what you posted above (**accidents.csv**):

```
Accident_ID,Region,Year
213,1,2003
214,1,2003
214,2,2008
213,2,2007
210,2,2007
210,3,2004
210,1,2004
213,1,2004
210,1,2004
```

This script reads the dataset, groups the data and builds a 3d histogram plot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pandas import read_csv
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Read CSV dataset file

df = read_csv('accidents.csv')

# Group by year and region

group_year_region = df.groupby(['Year', 'Region'])
group_keys = group_year_region.groups.keys()

# Get the years and regions series

xpos = map(lambda k: k[0] - 0.5, group_keys)
ypos = map(lambda k: k[1] - 0.5, group_keys)
zpos = [0] * len(xpos)

# Count number of accidents by (year, region) group

acc_by_year_region = group_year_region.count()['Accident_ID']

dx = 1
dy = 1
dz = [acc_by_year_region[key] for key in group_keys]

# Plot bar3d histogram

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')

# Years should not be presented in exponential notation

x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)

# Set labels and show plot

ax.set_xticks([k[0] for k in group_keys])
ax.set_yticks([k[1] for k in group_keys])
ax.set_zticks(dz)

ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_ylabel('Regions')
ax.set_zlabel('# Accidents')
plt.show()
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

### EDIT

There was a problem with the way the axes were built and the values were unordered. It is fixed now and the plot image has been updated.

Comment: AWESOME ! what do you mean by: dx,dy

Comment: Those parameters are the widths of the bars on the x and y axis respectively.

Comment: Can you please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024439/how-to-customize-axes-in-3d-hist-python-matplotlib

Comment: I am having problem   with the way the axis were built.

Comment: Check the new version of the script. I made a mistake in the previous version and the order in the *z* series wasn't the same as the one in the *x* and *y* series (the correspondence between year-region groups and # accidents wasn't the correct one).

Comment: ah OK! That's why I am getting confused. I am trying to debug it now. I am trying to use what you did but in different way. Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024439/how-to-customize-axes-in-3d-hist-python-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the shape of your data does not add up. You have three vectors, and they have to have the same length.

Running your example, years and Frequency_... have both 210 elements, but regions have only 99. I think what you want to do is to filter the accidents by region, for what you can use Panda's `groupby`.

Comment: I couldn't get you, Can you show an example. If I filter accidents by region I will end-up having dictinary of lists {region1:[accident1,accident2,..], region2:[accident11,accident12,..]}

Comment: You can do the groupby for years. Now you have {region1:[1980, 1991], region2:[2004, 2004, 2005]...}. Then, do a histogram on each region and plot it using collections3d or bar3d: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.add_collection3d