# How to customize axes in 3D hist python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to plot this data set using 3D bar

```
  B    A   freq
  1  2003     2
  1  2003     2
  2  2008     1
  2  2007     2
  2  2007     2
  3  2004     1
  1  2004     3
  1  2004     3
  1  2004     3
```

I have written the code here.

```
  data = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[2003,2003,2008,2007,2007,2004,2004,2004,2004] , 'B': [1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1] ,'C': [2,2,1,2,2,1,3,3,3] })
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        # put 0s on the y-axis, and put the y axis on the z-axis

        #ax.plot(data.A.values, data.B.values,data.freq.values, marker='o', linestyle='--', color="blue", label='ys=0, zdir=z')
        xpos= range(len( data.A.values))
        ypos= range(len( data.B.values))
        zpos= range(len( data.freq.values))

        ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, data.A.values, data.B.values,data.freq.values, color='b', alpha=0.5)

        x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)

        ax.set_xticks(data.A.values)
        ax.set_yticks(data.B.values)
        ax.set_zticks(data.freq.values)


        plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300)
        plt.show()
```

But it doesn't seem to be the right way to do that? Can any one help by showing how do we customize axes ?

It works when I use plot

```
ax.plot(data.A.values, data.B.values,data.freq.values,marker='o', linestyle='--', color='r')
```

instead of bar3D

```
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, data.A.values, data.B.values,data.freq.values, color='b', alpha=0.5)
```

but I wanna use 3D histogram for better understading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're misunderstanding the parameters on the **bar3d** function:

`bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz)`

- Parameters **x**, **y** and **z** are the coordinates of the bars on the x, y and z axis respectively.
- Parameters **dx**, **dy** and **dz** are the sizes of the bars on the x, y and z axis respectively.

For example, if you want to plot the following dataset:

`{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2003, 2008] ,'freq': [2, 3] }`

You have to define these parameters like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xpos = [1, 2]
ypos = [2003, 2008]
zpos = [0, 0]

dx = 1
dy = 1
dz = [2, 3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz)
plt.show()
```

This is:

- You plot one bar in **(1, 2003, 0)** (x, y, z) with height **2**.
- You plot one bar in **(2, 2008, 0)** (x, y, z) with height **3**.
- Both bars have a size of **1** on the x and y axis, it could be less though, it's just an aesthetic issue.

The script above generates the following plot:

[image]

If you look at the image you'll notice some minor format problems:

- Years are represented in exponential notation.
- Bars are not centered on their (x, y) coordinates.

We can actually solve this with a few tweaks:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xpos = [1, 2]
ypos = [2003, 2008]
zpos = [0, 0]

dx = 1
dy = 1
dz = [2, 3]

# Move each (x, y) coordinate to center it on the tick

xpos = map(lambda x: x - 0.5, xpos)
ypos = map(lambda y: y - 0.5, ypos)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz)

# Do not print years in exponential notation

y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)

plt.show()
```

And finally this is what we'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are too many places you got it wrong, so I'd just post what it should be like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1], 'B': [2003,2003,2008,2007,2007,2004,2004,2004,2004] ,'freq': [2,2,1,2,2,1,3,3,3] })
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# put 0s on the y-axis, and put the y axis on the z-axis

#ax.plot(data.A.values, data.B.values,data.freq.values, marker='o', linestyle='--', color="blue", label='ys=0, zdir=z')
PV = pd.pivot_table(data, values='freq',rows='A',cols='B')
xpos=np.arange(PV.shape[0])
ypos=np.arange(PV.shape[1])
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos=np.zeros(PV.shape).flatten()
dx=0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy=0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dz=PV.values.ravel()
dz[np.isnan(dz)]=0.

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color='b', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_xticks([.5,1.5,2.5])
ax.set_yticks([.5,1.5,2.5,3.5])
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(PV.columns)
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(PV.index)
ax.set_xlabel('A')
ax.set_ylabel('B')
ax.set_zlabel('Occurrence')

plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify how do you adjust axes. Let's = data= pandas.DataFrame({'A': np.random.rand(100)*1000 , 'B':np.random.rand(100)*10 ,'freq':np.random.rand(100)*2220  }) . should I change ax.set_xticks or w_yaxis.set_ticklabels , it's confusing a little bit

Comment: Yes, I think you would need to but you will first need to make a `pivot_table` from `DataFrame` `data`, you `ticks` and `ticklabels` are to be adjusted according to the pivot_table of `data`.